# Merge Sort using sentinels in C# produces weird outputs

Tags: c#, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement the merge sort algorithm using sentinels in C#.

The array I am trying to sort:

```cs
int[] arr = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 };
```

Here is my merge sort function:

```cs
void MergeSort(int[] arr, int lowerIndex, int upperIndex)
        {
            if (upperIndex > lowerIndex)
            {
                int midIndex = (lowerIndex + upperIndex) / 2;
                MergeSort(arr, lowerIndex, midIndex);
                MergeSort(arr, midIndex + 1, upperIndex);
                Merge(arr, midIndex, lowerIndex, upperIndex);

            }
        }
```

Here is my merge function:

```cs
 void Merge(int[] arr, int midIndex, int lowerIndex, int upperIndex)
        {
            int leftArrayLength = midIndex - lowerIndex + 1;
            int rightArrayLength = upperIndex - midIndex;

            int[] left = new int[leftArrayLength + 1];
            int[] right = new int[rightArrayLength + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < leftArrayLength; i++)
            {
                left[i] = arr[i];
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < rightArrayLength; j++)
            {
                left[j] = arr[midIndex + j];
            }

            //Sentinels
            left[leftArrayLength] = int.MaxValue;
            right[rightArrayLength] = int.MaxValue;

            int m = 0;
            int n = 0;
            for (int k = lowerIndex; k <= upperIndex; k++)
            {
                if (left[m] <= right[n])
                {
                    arr[k] = left[m];
                    m += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    arr[k] = right[n];
                    n += 1;
                }

            }
        }
```

It's giving a weird output:

```
0 0 0 7 0 4
```

I have so far repeatedly checked my implementation following the pseudocode given in CLRS, but I am failing to find what's wrong with my implementation.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: did you check it here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: @StefanW. yes I actually did go through this before posting it here, but I couldn't find much help from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least next several errors in the `left`/`right` array initialization:

- for `left` you should start from `lowerIndex`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < leftArrayLength; i++)
{
    left[i] = arr[lowerIndex + i];
}
```

- for `right` there are two errors - 1) a typo for array name and use `left` 2) "off-by-one error" for index

```
for (int j = 0; j < rightArrayLength; j++)
{
   right[j] = arr[midIndex + 1 + j];
}
```